# How small the radical of $xy(x+y)uv(u+v)$ can be infinitely often?

Tags: nt.number-theory, abc-conjecture

Let $x,y,u,v$ be positive integers with $x,y$ coprime and $u,v$ coprime
( $xy,uv$ not necessarily coprime). Assume $x+y \ne u+v$.

How small the radical of $xy(x+y)uv(u+v)$ can be infinitely often?

Can we get $O(|(x+y)(u+v)|^{1-C})$ for $C>0$?

These are just two pairs of good $abc$ triples so we can get $C=0$
with pairwise coprimality.

Comment: Couldn't you just let $x=u,y=v$ be some prime powers?

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks, this is solution. Let me try to fix the question if possible at all.

Comment: @Wojowu I edited trying to remove your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution where the radical is $O(k^9)$ and $(x+y)(u+v)=O(k^{12})$

The idea is that $x,y,z=a^2,b^2,c^2$ for a Pythagorean triple and $u,v,u+v=A^2,B^2,C^2$ for another with $C=c^2.$ I used the most familiar type of triple (hypotenuse and long leg differ by $1$), there might be others that do better, or special values of $k.$

- $x=(2k+1)^2$
- $y=\left(2k(k+1)\right)^2$
- $u=(y^2-x^2)^2=((2k^2-1)(2k^2+4k+1))^2$
- $v=(2xy)^2=(4k(k+1)(2k+1))^2$

then

- $x+y=(2k^2+2k+1)^2$
- $u+v=(2k^2+2k+1)^4$

Thus $(x+y)(u+v)=O(k^{12})$

But the radical of $xy(x+y)uv(u+v)$ is at most

$$k(k+1)(2k+1)(2k^2-1)(2k^2+2k+1)(2k^2+4k+1)=O(k^9)$$

Comment: Thanks! Minor issue:  O(k^12) includes O(k), so probably you mean $\sim k^{12}$.

Comment: You can improve the exponent $\frac9{12}$ to $\frac8{12}$ by choosing $k$ so that $2k^2+4k+1$ is a square. That might be the limit of that particular construction.

Comment: Indeed. You can improve it by setting k=2^N too.

Comment: That is true and easier to see. In a certain sense, what I described seems better, on average,  for $k<20000$ and to be near optimal. But another construction entirely might get your exponent $1-C$ below $0.6$ infinitely often.

Comment: Can you get x+y and u+v coprime?

Comment: Not at the moment. What is the best you can do for the radical of $xy(x+y)$ relative to $x+y?$

Comment: abc implies the radical of $xy(x+y)$ can't be smaller than $(x+y)^{1-C}$ for positive $C$ and coprime x,y infinitely often.

Comment: Does this work:  set A,B,C,D large powers of small primes or one. Let x=Ar,y=Bs,u=Cr;v=Ds. Then the radical is at most rs(Ar+Bs)(Cr+Ds). Try to find one small solution of (Ar+Bs)(Cr+Ds)=t^k for some k.

Comment: We answered with exponent 2/3 with x+y and u+v coprime. This construction is related to an open problem.

Comment: You might be interested in similar problem: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378730/how-small-the-radical-of-xyzxyz-can-be-infinitely

Answer (score 1):

We got solutions with $x+y,u+v$ coprime and exponent 10/12
as polynomials and exponent 2/3 over the integers.

- $x=(t - r)^2 * (t + r)^2$
- $y=(4) * r^2 * t^2$
- $u=(t - r)^2 * (t + r)^2 * (t^2 + r^2)^2$
- $v=(4) * r^4 * t^4$

Comment: I understand the 10/12 but what do you do to get 2/3 infinitely often?

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz To get 2/3, I set r=2^large, t=3^large. The radical is divisible by rt, the perfect powers are only 6 in the radical, so I remove degree 2 from the radical (10-2)/12=8/12=2/3. ( there is alternative approach, but it is complicated).