# How small the radical of $xyz(x+y+z)$ can be infinitely?

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems, abc-conjecture

This is an open problem.

Let $x,y,z$ be coprime integers (not necessarily pairwise coprime)
and no proper subset sum of $\{x,y,z,-(x+y+z)\}$ is zero.

For a quadruple $(x,y,z,-(x+y+z))$ define the quality
$$q(x,y,z,-(x+y+z))=\frac{\log{(\max(|x|,|y|,|z|,|x+y+z|))}}{\log(rad(xyz(x+y+z))}$$
where $rad$ is the radical.

We have quality $q= 3+o(1)$ given by
$$x=1, y=3 (t - 1)  t, z=(t - 1)^3, -(x+y+z)=-t^3$$
and at integers set $t=2^{large}$.

> Can we get quality $3+C$ infinitely often for positive $C$?

Comment: Not quite as good, but you can get $3-o(1)$ by arranging that $t-1$ and $t$ are a square and twice a square.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz You can reduce the radical of general, possibly irreducible f(x) to x^(degree(f(x))-1) by solving f(x)=0 mod p^n.